# Getting unknown length of nsstring out of nsstring

Tags: nsstring

So I have this long string that looks like this

```
{
    available = yes;
    from = player1;
    imageid = 13623367787816752r;
    time = 1367787816752;
}
```

There will always be a different length of imageid so I'm woundering how can I get the image id value only?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use an [`NSScanner`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You could scan for "available = ", then "yes;" or "no;", etc. until you're at the imageid. Once there, scan for characters in the set of numbers and letters, but not including a semicolon. (Or whatever is appropriate for your situation.)